# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error on writing to a table in database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to read a data from one database table using java + jdbc and trying to insert into another database table on different server in same session.

I have created 2 connection object(con,conn1), each pointing to correct database.
With 1st con object i am able to read the data but  When it is going to write the data to another table using conn1 it is failing with error
ORA-00942- table or view doesnt exist.

I have also cross-checked that table is present and we can write to that table.
with a standalone class and static data i was able to write to that table.

Please let me know what is wrong in my approach.

Code sample:

public static void main

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "URL","uname","passwd");
```

//code to read from db and add to arraylist.
close resultset, con.

This connection obj points to new a database and url

Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection( "url","uname","passwd");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement("insert into SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME(columns) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

//code to iterate the arraylist populated above

```
pstmt.setint etc 
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

It fails after executeUpdate statement.

Comment: Post some code which demonstrates your problem. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: added fragments of code. Please check

Comment: Your approach is right :)

Comment: additional info, i am reading to and writing to a clob field also in the above queries. Is this creating a problem? Clob field is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, problem was with pstmt.setClob field. I changed it to pstmt.setString and took .toString() of clob object and it worked.

I m still puzzled why it throws table or view doesnt exist error.

Comment: Ok, so the exact reason is when we do pstmt.setClob using ojdbc14.jar driver it gives table or view doesnt work. So i updated the driver to ojdbc6.jar and used pstmt.setClob(clob.getCharacterStream) and viola the tables got migrated. Just posting this answer for future reference